# A question about reverse printing a linked list

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

The question [reverse print an immutable linkedlist with less than O(n) space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41542257/754550) is put on hold. The reason is

> this question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center

The  question is

> 1. If any better and more elegant ideas to achieve the same goal (reverse print an immutable linkedlist with less than O(n) space)?
> 2. Any code bugs, and/or algorithm performance (in terms of time complexity) improvement ideas?

So it asks about an improvement of  or a  better

> - a software algorithm, ...

as required by the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

What is wrong with this question?

Comment: As the first comment on the question states, Stack Overflow isn't really the place for code with no problems. As for the second part of the question, it is way, *way* too broad.

Comment: Someone already commented on your question, that you should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead. I do agree that the help center could be more clear on this.

Comment: Question #1 is pretty much opinionated, there is no standard measure for "elegant" so anyone who has some other idea of doing exactly the same will be forced to post it; which code will be "better" will be up to the interpretation of each and every reader. That's not what Stack Overflow is for, its designed for factual Q&A. Question #2 is fully a code review question. And the icing on the cake: asking two questions at once is generally considered too broad.

Comment: @Gimby: To say that sombody is forced to post something is rather exaggerated. That is not the way stackexchange works. Nobody is forced to post anything.

Comment: @miracle173 "obliged".

Comment: I've improved @miracle173's edit that removes too broad part and voted to reopen. Maybe even better answer will come that explains why there is no way to get better estimate - also it theoretical part could be better suited for [CS.SE] - no idea what is on-topic there...

Comment: Algorithm development is *certainly* ontopic on [cs.SE]. We would ask the OP to move from Python to pseudocode and give answers using such. Code (or even algorithm) review is not something we like, though. Unless there are specific questions, we'd probably close. In any case, if you think a question is too theoretical for [SO] it's *probably* fine for [cs.SE].

Answer (score 24):

The closure of this question was invalid, at least for the reason given. What happened is, Burhan voted to close the question for the following reason:

> If your code is working fine, but you just need ideas to improve it - the best place to ask is http://codereview.stackexchange.com

The only place to leave a custom comment when you vote to close a question is under the "off-topic" category, and when you do this, the system automatically posts your custom close reason as a comment to the question. There is no other way that the custom close reason shows up—it does not appear in the yellow "closed" box; that simply says "closed as off-topic".

Presumably, the other 4 close-voters all agreed with Burhan that this question would be a better fit over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (and reasonably so). They therefore followed his example and voted to close the question for the custom reason that Burhan gave, which, confusingly, *does* appear directly in the close-vote dialog for them to select.

Broadly speaking, I see three things that went wrong here:

1. The fact that all custom closure reasons appear under the "off topic" category created confusion, because you looked at the question and said: "Wait a minute! This is *clearly* not off-topic; it is about a practical programming problem and even includes the relevant code!" You were correct; the closure system is confusing in how its options are categorized. This question is not obviously off-topic, and you were right to question that assessment.
2. The fact that a question would be a better fit on a different site *does not* make it off-topic on the original site. There are, for example, bunches of questions on Super User that would probably be a *better* fit on either Ask Different or Unix/Linux, but that doesn't make them off-topic for Super User. As an active member of a particular community, when you see a question that you think would make a great fit for that community, you are free to recommend that the person ask it there, instead. However, you should *not* vote to close the question as off-topic unless it is actually off-topic for the site on which it was originally asked. The topic area of Code Review is a natural subset of what is on-topic for Stack Overflow (with a few exceptions—see below).
3. That said, this question probably *should* have been closed on Stack Overflow, but for a different reason than the one that was actually picked. Rather than being "off topic", it is actually "too broad" because it asks too many different things, many of which are nebulous and primarily opinion-based.

If it were me, I'd have voted to close the question as "too broad" and left a comment similar to the one that Burhan left. That would ensure that the question got closed for an ostensibly valid reason, but still provide guidance to the asker that their question didn't totally suck and that there is another place where they could get an answer.

Comment: *"Presumably, the other 4 close-voters all agreed with Burhan"* - wait, isn't a majority all that's needed for a close reason to become the one that is displayed? For all we know, couldn't only a single close-voter have agreed with Burhan, with another voting that the question was too broad, another that it was unclear, and another that it was opinion-based?

Comment: That's true, and why I used the word "presumably". I don't know for sure, but that seems the most likely explanation.